# How can I install adobe flash

Tags: adobe, pepperflash

I new and using Ubuntu 18.04, but I try to install adobe flash,I cannot:

```
E: unable to locate package adobe-flashplugin
E: unable to locate package browser-plugin-flash-player-pepperflash
```

Comment: sudo apt install flashplugin-installer

Comment: Did you activate partner repository?

Comment: Flash will not be supported after December, so it might become a security problem.  Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal using `Ctrl+Alt+T` execute one by one,

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Then execute the command.

Packages are available here [browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash) and [flashplugin-installer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/flashplugin-installer)

Comment: Thanks, this worked.